# Linq GroupJoin exception

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a similar query in my code trying to perform a group join:

```
var query = from client in _clientsRepository.Query()
            join order in _ordersRepository.Query()
            on client.Id equals order.Client.Id into orders
            select new Model(client, orders);
```

It's almost identical to the 101 Linq Samples, however, whenever I run it I get
the following exception:

> {"Unable to cast object of type
>   'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause' to type
>   'Remotion.Linq.Clauses.FromClauseBase'."}

Not sure why this is happening and I can't find any answers on the Web.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
 at NHibernate.Linq.GroupJoin.GroupJoinAggregateDetectionVisitor.VisitQuerySourceReferenceExpression(QuerySourceReferenceExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitAndConvert[T](T expression, String methodName)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitList[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 list, Func`2 visitMethod)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitNewExpression(NewExpression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.NhExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.GroupJoin.GroupJoinAggregateDetectionVisitor.Visit(IEnumerable`1 groupJoinClause, Expression selectExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.GroupJoin.AggregatingGroupJoinRewriter.ReWrite(QueryModel model)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I wouldn't even expect that to compile - the `order` range variable isn't available after `into orders`

Comment: @JonSkeet Could a shadowed member of some kind result in this behavior?

Comment: @Servy: Possibly. I think we could basically do with more information here...

Comment: @JonSkeet Nevertheless, it does compile. Please see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b for reference. They are identical.

Comment: @Constantinos Your code differs from that code, in a small but important enough way to cause it to (in theory) not compile, at least not as shown.

Comment: @Constantinos: Which example are you looking at?

Comment: I just edited the question. I missed an 's'.

Comment: @Constantinos: Right, that makes *all* the difference. So is that the code that actually fails? What does the full stack trace look like? This looks like it's a Remotion issue, basically.

Comment: @JonSkeet The group join one.

Comment: I ve added the stacktrace if anyone is still interested